# Java Sound API: Attempt to Do Live Microphone Input Monitoring is Slow

Tags: java, audio, real-time, javasound, low-latency

I think I have a performance (latency) issue with the Java Sound API.

**Audio Monitor**

The following code does indeed work for me.  It correctly opens up the microphone, and outputs the audio input through my speakers in real time (i.e. monitoring).  But my concern is the speed of which the playback happens... it is half a second behind from when I speak into my microphone till playback through my speakers.

How do I increase performance?  How do I lower the latency?

```
private void initForLiveMonitor() {

    AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100, 16, 2, 4, 44100, false);

    try {

        //Speaker
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
        SourceDataLine sourceLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        sourceLine.open();

        //Microphone
        info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
        TargetDataLine targetLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        targetLine.open();

        Thread monitorThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                targetLine.start();
                sourceLine.start();

                byte[] data = new byte[targetLine.getBufferSize() / 5];
                int readBytes;

                while (true) {
                    readBytes = targetLine.read(data, 0, data.length);
                    sourceLine.write(data, 0, readBytes);
                }
            }
        };

        System.out.println( "Start LIVE Monitor for 15 seconds" );
        monitorThread.start();

        Thread.sleep(15000);
        targetLine.stop();
        targetLine.close();
        System.out.println( "End LIVE Monitor" );

    }
    catch(LineUnavailableException lue) { lue.printStackTrace(); }
    catch(InterruptedException ie) { ie.printStackTrace(); }


}
```

**Additional Notes**

- With this code, the playback is smooth (no pops nor jitters), just half a second delayed.
- I also know that my computer and USB Audio interface are capable to handle real-time monitoring through the computer, because when I do a side-by-side comparison with Logic Pro X there are minimal delays--I perceive no delay at all.
- My attempts at making smaller/larger the byte[] size haven't helped the issue.

My conclusion, is that this is a Java code issue I have.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would seem to come down to how big `targetLine.getBufferSize()` is. How many bytes is that?

Comment: @AndrewThompson The method `targetLine.getBufferSize()` returns 88200 bytes.  I've already played with the divisor of the `byte[]` with little change.  When I brought the `byte[]` explicitly down to 4 bytes, it indeed helped, but I still perceive a quarter second delay (from over half a second delay).

Comment: The size of byte[] that you set does not pertain to the buffer in the DataLine. You need to include the size in the open() methods to set DataLine buffer sizes, e.g. .open(size). 88200 bytes at 4 bytes per frame and 44100 frames per second accounts for the half-second delay. Shortening too much could create dropouts but I'm pretty sure there are safe values you can set that have less latency. See my answer below.

Comment: Use JackAudio or ALSA API for real-time capture and playback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more than one buffer involved!

When you open the SourceDataLine and TargetDataLine, I'd recommend using the form where you specify the buffer size. But I don't know what size to recommend. I haven't played around with this enough to know what the optimum size is for safely piping microphone input--my experience is more with real-time synthesis.

Anyway, how about this: define the length of data[] and use the same length in your line opening methods. Try numbers like 1024 or multiples (while making sure the number of bytes can be evenly divided by the per-frame number of bytes which looks to be 4 according to the format you are using).

```
int bufferLen = 1024 * 4;  // experiment with buffer size here

byte[] data = new byte[bufferLen];
sourceLine.open(bufferLen);
targetLine.open(bufferLen);
```

Also, maybe code in your run() would be better placed elsewhere so as not to add to the required processing before the piping can even start. The array data[] and int readBytes could be instance variables and ready to roll rather than being dinked with in the run(), potentially adding to the latency.

Those are things I'd try, anyway.

Comment: "The array data[] and int readBytes could be instance variables and ready to roll rather than being dinked with in the run(), potentially adding to the latency." these are small chips in big potatoes; if he says he tried different buffer sizes then thats it! - "There is more than one buffer involved!": where?? I'd like to know specifically where? and that would affect his performance

Comment: API explicitly talks of setting a buffer size for DataLines. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/SourceDataLine.html#open-javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat-int- There is also one for the TargetDataLine.

Comment: Thanks Phil.  Yes the latency did indeed go down with setting the bufferSize for both open() methods too.  I'd estimate that the latency is improved now down to a 10th of a second (better from quarter of a second).  And experimenting with the buffer size 1024 * 2 worked without causing distortion issues.  Going anywhere below that caused audible issues.

Comment: Glad this was helpful. BTW, I would not rule out the possibility that having different buffer sizes for the different lines might give more improvements. It could be worth setting up an edge cases and testing independent size settings for the different buffers. As I said, I haven't done this myself. There might be different tolerances for the different lines/stages.